# android : Relative layout width wrap_content

Tags: android, imageview, width, android-relativelayout

I have following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/personal_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dom_logo_new" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_top_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/corner_white_left_top" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_top_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/corner_white_right_top" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/corner_white_left_bottom" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/corner_white_right_bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is 1 main image (personal_image) and 4 small images.

I need display main image (personal_image) at center horizontal of the screen with 4 images at its each corner (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right). but `RelativeLayout` has width and height of all screen.

How can I set the `width` and the `height` of `RelativeLayout` the same `width` and `height` of personal_image??

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/personal_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_top_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_top_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner_bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/round_corner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you are using wrap content you donot have to worry about different screen sizes.it will manage by its own.

Comment: it doesnt work.. small images set the relative layout max width and height

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) instead of corner images which is the Android way to solve such issues.